# Using NVDA with Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, nvda

I use a screen reader called NVDA to navigate my computer. I use notepad++ for all my coding. It works fine except that when I put the mouse cursor on a line, NVDA reads five lines below where my cursor is. Normally, NVDA reads the line I have my cursor over in everything else on my computer. Why is it only with Notepad++ does it read five lines below? How can I fix this so NVDA reads the line my cursor is on in Notepad++ and not five lines below my cursor?

Comment: Probably best to contact the company. Unfortunately, this is off-topic as it's not a programming question.

Comment: @DavidMakogon a question is on topic if "covers software tools commonly used by programmers;" So yes, for instance configuring Visual Studio or setting up the environment for coding (in this case Notepad++) **is on-topic**

Comment: Does this issue still persist at your end? I don't quite experience it with Notepad++7.6 & NVDA 2018.3.2.